How to set up a browser without remembering basic authentication
I'm creating an HttpListener with AuthenticationSchemes.Basic. At the first request, the browser will prompt you to enter authentication. If we refresh the page (F5), the browser will no longer prompt for authentication. How can I make every browser request prompt for authentication?
P.S. If you read the request cookies in the browser, authentication will be required again.
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var listener = new HttpListener();
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:1111/");
    
    listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
    listener.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Ctrl+C to stop.");

    while (true)
    {
        var context = listener.GetContext();
        var request = context.Request;
        var response = context.Response;

        if (request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html>Happy end</html>");
            response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"\"");
            response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
            response.OutputStream.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            response.StatusCode = 401;
            response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"MyServer\"");
            response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
            response.OutputStream.Close();
        }
        response.Close();
    }
}

An authentication request must be made for each request.

You can't, browsers are made to remember the basic authentication credentials. Unless your server takes a different password each request the browser will hapily remember them for the user.

Also look at this somewhat related question from SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/917602/how-do-i-log-out-with-http-basic

"I'm creating an HttpListener with AuthenticationSchemes.Basic" why? In fact, why are you re-creating ASP.NET in the first place?
